# Hot Network Questions

Tags: discussion, support

Why does Poker never get on the hot network question list?

There was a poker question from board games on the list.

Comment: Maybe because the community is too small to actually generate enough traffic to breach the threshold? That'd be my guess.

Comment: @Seth I looked it up and there is and activity equation

Comment: @Paparazzi perhaps you could post the equation and a link for future reference if people come across this question? I for one would be interested to know the mechanics of how questions make it onto the Hot Network Questions (I'd be surprised if there isn't a question on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) about this).

Comment: Yup, I think [this Meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page) has the info? Is that what you found @Paparazzi?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's detailed in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/344265) Meta answer:

> Basically what's documented here:
>
> > [What formula should be used to determine "hot" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions)
>
> We have a few tweaks:
>
> - Succeeding questions from the same site are penalized by increasing amounts.  So, the first question from SO in the list gets multiplied
>     by 1.0, the second by 0.98, the third by 0.96, etc)
> - We make a per-site traffic adjustment so SO does not dominate the entire list
> - The benefit of many answers is capped at 10
> - We only degrade based on question age, and not the last update date on a question, so questions don't pop back up to the top every time
>     they're edited
> - Views are not counted towards the score
>
> The core of the formula (without the site-based degrading or traffic
>   scaling) is:
>
> ```
> (MIN(AnswerCount, 10) * QScore) / 5 + AnswerScore
>  -------------------------------------------------
>         MAX(QAgeInHours + 1, 6) ^ 1.4
> ```

So for example, [this question](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/8542/versus-random-hands) which has one answer with a score of 3, a question score of 3 and is 48 hours old would score `0.0017` whereas [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381264/show-button-only-when-view-is-responsive-mobile-size) from SO would score about `0.054` (both before traffic scaling), so over 30 times higher scoring than the Poker.SE question.